# ERC20 convert decimal value to uint

Tags: solidity, erc-20

In our platform, we reward users with `ERC20` tokens based on the fixed formula.

> number of articles user wrote * 0.01828 = number of tokens to be rewarded

So let's say a user wrote 5 articles (5 * 0.01828), they get 0.3656 tokens.

How do I convert that to `uint256` so EVM can accept it?

p.s. I set my decimals places to 18.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are dealing with token amounts it is possible to use fixed point arithmetic using the 18 decimals.

For example

```
function numTokens(uint articles) public pure returns (uint) {
    // Solc accepts numbers with decimals at compile time
    uint coef = 0.01828 * 10**18;
    // coef is 18280000000000000 and can be stored as an uint

    return articles * coef;
}
```